# Как правильно настроить функцию для одинаковых элементов?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно настроить функцию для нескольких одинаковых элементов?
Вот код:

```
<div class="plaudio" data="1">text</div>
<div class="plaudio" data="2">text</div>`
<div class="plaudio" data="1">text</div>
  <audio id="myaudio" loop ><source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis" /> </audio>
<script>
function audiopl(){
var plaudio = document.getElementsByClassName('plaudio');
for( var i=0; i<plaudio.length; ++i ) {
var obj = plaudio[i];
var ell = obj.getAttribute('data');
if (ell != 1) { 
document.getElementById("myaudio").pause();
} 
else {
document.getElementById("myaudio").play(); 
}
}
}
audiopl();</script>
```

но этот код срабатывает только для последнего элемента, как сделать что бы он срабатывал на все элементы у которых будет data="1"?

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, что Вы пытаетесь сделать. Сейчас приведенный код в цикле пробегает не останавливаясь по всем `class="plaudio"` элементам, и, конечно, Вы видите эффект последнего.

Comment: Особое внимание уделите смыслу фразы: "что бы он срабатывал на все элементы".

Comment: А ничего, что вы меняете состояние **одного и того же** элемента `audio`? Так что ваш код срабатывает для каждого `div.plaudio` но имеет эффект только `data` аттрибут последнего найденного тега... Ваш код делает ровно то, что должен безотносительно того, что вы от него хотите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код:

```
function audiopl(){
    var plaudio = document.getElementsByClassName('plaudio');
    for( var i=0; i<plaudio.length; ++i ){
        var obj = plaudio[i];
        var ell = obj.getAttribute('data');
        if (ell == 1) { 
            document.getElementById("myaudio").play(); 
            console.log("play");
        } 
        else {
            document.getElementById("myaudio").pause();
            console.log("pause");
        }
    }
}
audiopl();
```

Рабочий пример [здесь](http://jsbin.com/xatofi/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: код вроде рабочий, в консоле показывает что все правильно, но если у последнего тега div в data поставить 2 например, то аудио не срабатывает, хотя в консоле показывает play

Comment: Код при прохождении по цыклу, для каждого элемента с класом "plaudio" включается или выключается одна и та же запись. Из этого вытекает что последний элемент указывает играть или не играть файл.

Comment: я понял свою ошибку, спасибо!